# Clang CodeGen Builder CreatCall to GCC Builtin Function

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I want to modify the clang codegen module to create a gcc builtin function (e.g. __builtin_frame_address) call using Builder.createCall method. Any suggestion how to do that?

Comment: For `__builtin_frame_address` specifically you can use [`llvm.frameaddress`](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-frameaddress-intrinsic).

Comment: thanks, that helps.